# Bash - put each sentence of a file on a diferent line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I need to read the length of each sentence on a text file.

I planned to separate each sentence on a different line and then read each line.

```
# LineSplitter

File="NameOfFile"

while read -r line; do
    # check the neght of $line
done <$file
```

I tried using `tr` to replace `.` for `\n` but this removes the `.` and does not work for questions.

Solutions for the LineSplitter?

It should be like this

Initial file:

```
SMS marketing is an excellent customer service tool because messages are delivered and read almost immediately — and there’s room for two-way communication. And SMS customer service can be scaled and automated. Plus, if you leverage this channel, your business will save money on phone service and customer service personnel training.


See a few templates for customer support messages below.
```

Final

```
SMS marketing is an excellent customer service tool because messages are delivered and read almost immediately — and there’s room for two-way communication.
And SMS customer service can be scaled and automated.
Plus, if you leverage this channel, your business will save money on phone service and customer service personnel training.
See a few templates for customer support messages below.
```

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: will the input *always* consist of a single line of text, or could the input (and thus some sentences) span multiple lines?

Comment: Is `He said "I need help." so I helped.` a sentence? What about `I had 1.5 miles to go.`? My point is, it's hard (probably impossible) to write a tool that can parse natural language to determine where sentences begin/end since all of the characters that might indicate the end of a sentence can exist **within** a sentence in other contexts. So, if you have a **small subset** of natural language you need help writing a tool to parse, that is do-able but you'd have to provide the grammar and rules for that language along with comprehensive examples of it.

Comment: Since it is hard to find exact requirements for splitting the text into lines, you might like to explain what your purpose is. Count length of each line for what purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\. /&\n/g' input_file
SMS marketing is an excellent customer service tool because messages are delivered and read almost immediately — and there’s room for two-way communication. 
And SMS customer service can be scaled and automated. 
Plus, if you leverage this channel, your business will save money on phone service and customer service personnel training. 
See a few templates for customer support messages below.
```